# Paramiko `exec_command` timeout only works for short timeout, and exception type doesn't match

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

My Python script runs a remote command over `ssh`, using the Paramiko library's `exec_command` function.  To test the `timeout` option to this command, I'm sending a do-nothing loop, and verifying that the `exec_command` function times out.  However, the timeout only fires when I set it to a value less than `1`.  For example, the following code times out as expected:

```
command = 'while true; do :; done'
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.connect(ip, port=port, username=user, pkey=key, timeout=10)
_, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command, timeout=0.5)
print("Running command: {}".format(command))
exit_code = stdout.channel.recv_exit_status()
```

But when I change the `timeout` argument value to `1`, it does not time out.

Another odd thing is that when the timeout does occur (with the `0.5` arg value), the exception type is `paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException`, rather than `socket.timeout`, as the docs say it should be.  The full exception message is `paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Timeout openning channel.`  But the stack trace starts at the `exec_command` line above, not the `connect` line:

```
Running command: while true; do :; done
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./t.py", line 40, in <module>
    _, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command, timeout=0.5)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 414, in exec_command
    chan = self._transport.open_session(timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 703, in open_session
    timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 828, in open_channel
    raise SSHException('Timeout openning channel.')
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Timeout openning channel.
```

So I have two questions:

- Why does a timeout of `0.5` work, but `1` or greater does not?
- Why does the exception report a timeout opening the channel, instead of a `socket.timeout`, even though the exception is coming from `exec_command`, not `connect`?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `timeout` argument of [`SSHClient.exec_command`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.exec_command) has two purposes:

- Time limit for opening the SSH "exec" channel.

  This is where the timeout for 0.5s is probably triggered, as it takes longer to open the channel on your server. I.e. the timeout has nothing to do with your infinite command.

  If you set longer timeout (1s), the channel succeeds to open.

  This indeed throws `SSHException` (*"Timeout opening channel."*).
- Time limit for blocking operations, like reading/writing. You are not doing any reading/writing. This would throw `socket.timeout`.

  [`Channel.recv_exit_status`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/channel.html#paramiko.channel.Channel.recv_exit_status) does not seem to use the `timeout`. It waits forever.